# Bisectors of angles of circle

Tags: circles

Bisectors of angles $A$, $B$ and $C$ of a triangle $ABC$ intersect its circumcircle at $D$, $E$ and $F$ respectively.  Prove that the angles of the triangle $DEF$ are $90^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}A$, $90^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}B$ and $90^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}C$.

Comment: Hint : Use 'Angle in the same segments are equal' and 'Sum of opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral are $180$'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Using the following theorems:

$1$ : 'Sum of opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral are $180$'

$2$ : 'Angles in the same segments are equal'

$$\angle BDC = 180-\angle A$$
$$\angle EDC = \angle EBC = \angle \dfrac{B}{2}$$
$$\angle FDB = \angle FCB = \angle \dfrac{C}{2}$$ 
$$\angle FDE = \angle BDC - \angle EBC - \angle FCB$$
$$\angle FDE = 180-\angle A - \angle \dfrac{B}{2} - \angle \dfrac{C}{2}$$
$$\angle FDE = 90 - \angle \dfrac{A}{2}$$

Similarly we get the other two angles as $90 - \angle \dfrac{B}{2},90 - \angle \dfrac{C}{2}$

Hope the answer is clear !